# Ckeditor Table size exceeds the size of the page

Tags: ckeditor

I can drag the width of tables larger than the size of the content box as horizontal scroll is enabled. Is there a way to turn this off

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the resizing off completely

```
// See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableNativeTableHandles
config.disableNativeTableHandles = true;

// See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableObjectResizing
config.disableObjectResizing = true;
```

However it's not perfect:

- http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9317
- http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10197

If you want to enable it, but constrain it you might have to add some kind of hack to see if the table is too large and then resize it automatically. If that's what you want have a look at the change event: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change - hook into that event and when it is fired, check if it's a resize event and if the table is too wide and automatically resize it smaller yourself by code.